# How to Get SharePoint field internal name using Display Name?

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfield

In SharePoint list I know the field display name.

Using display name I want to get Internal name of field,

```
string FieldName = "Test Field";
SPField field = olist.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldname);
```

Test Field is display name using this how can i get the internal name of field without using foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it as below:

```
string FieldName = "Test Field";

//you can pass the display name, internal name of static name in the GetField method
SPField field = olist.Fields.GetField(FieldName);

var fieldInternalName = field.InternalName;
```

According to this - [SPFieldCollection.GetField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.getfield.aspx) , the `GetField` methods gives you the field data by passing it a string with either internal, display, or static name of the field.

Or alternatively, you can use it as below:

```
string FieldName = "Test Field";    

//accepts the fields display name only
SPField field = olist.Fields[FieldName];

var fieldInternalName = field.InternalName;
```

Reference - [SPFieldCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457291(v=office.15).aspx) property to get the field data.

After that, you can use the `InternalName` and fetch your value.

Reference - [SPField.InternalName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.internalname.aspx)

Comment: in my case both its not working 
if i am using this SPField field = olist.Fields.GetField(FieldName); error - Column 'Test Field' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

if i am using this  SPField field = olist.Fields(fieldname); //It was throwing Excpection.

Comment: thats quite strange, can you check if the spaces are correct or if the display name has some other characters ? you can go to list settings and check that